# why won't github pages render my code blocks correctly?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm using the https://github.com/mmistakes/so-simple-theme which is really nice.  It seems like last night github was correctly highlighting my fenced code blocks.  locally, in development, everything seems to be good.  but when I push to the github repo, fenced code blocks are not product the proper html structure to ensure code gets hightlight.  I'm not sure how to display this in my SO post.

given the below repo

https://github.com/rubyonrailstutor/rubyonrailstutor.github.io

consider this screenshot

[image]

the page displayed on the left has the correct html structure, the page on the right, the github page, displaying the same code as on the left does not.  what can I be looking at to further debug this?  thanks.

and for some more depth, i'm using kramdown style ~~~ which

```
#### modify spec/spec_helper.rb

~~~ruby
  config.expect_with :rspec do |c|
    c.syntax = :expect
  end
~~~ 

#### modify spec/models/restaurant_spec.rb

~~~ ruby
  require 'spec_helper'

  describe Restaurant do
    subject(:restaurant) { FactoryGirl.build(:restaurant, name: nil)}
    it {expect(restaurant.valid?).to be_false}
  end
~~~
```

Answer (score 3):

there is definitely a problem using

```
~~~ ruby

  #some code

~~~
```

instead of kramdown I had to use

```
{% highlight ruby %}

{% endhighlight %}
```

I'm not sure how I feel about this.